# What is the correct technical term for this "pool house" on my villa?

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

I have built a small "pool type" house on my estate villa. The house has a separate entrance, so where I enter the villa via my secure gates, the villa sits on the side. It has separate rooms and is completely closed off from my garden; you can only enter it from the street. I plan to rent it out to tenants.

The tenants have asked if there is a technical term for this type of property?

Below is a picture of it. You can see the building on the left. (The door and two lights)

[image: villa]

Comment: You say "the villa sits on the side". Do you mean this structure that you don't know the name of , _that_ sits on the side?

Comment: *Detached guest house?*

Comment: *Illegal*, unless there's enough means of egress; "only enter from..."

Comment: @Mitch. I meant that his villa entrance is on the side of the house on the right and that is a long driveway to the main house. This house sits on the left and is much smaller and is at the start of the garden adjacent to his entrance.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I know what you're talking about now, but it was unclear which buildings you were referring to when you use 'house' and 'villa' (sometimes you seem to use it for the main house, others for the unnamed smaller building with the street door). Also, it would help to know if this is mostly for British or American readers or some Caribbean island (this could change the relevant vocabulary considerably).

Comment: A realtor (real estate agent) would know best. For me (AmE), this _kind_ of building not necessarily matching exactly what you have, would be called a carriage house, because (in older cities, when people had carriages I guess) there'd be a separate small stable/building for a carriage or car that is converted to living arrangements. I guess it is the same as a garage for a house, but 'carriage house' conveys that it is entirely a residence, not some living space above a garage. This is probably not what you want to call your new building, but is functionally the closest specially-named thing.

Comment: It is in the UAE. I just wanted to have an address or building name for post and general usage. The current name is Out House

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One technical term is a **lodge** (or *estate lodge,* or *porter's lodge*). They were cottages which were adjacent to the main gates of an estate, intended to allow gatekeepers accommodation so they could open the gates as needed.

They could be outside or inside the main gates of the estate. Yours is outside.

Here's another with its principal doorway outside the main gates to the estate: this is the Gate Lodge on the [Dalmunzie Estate](https://www.dalmunzieestate.com/cottages/gate-lodge-south/) near Pitlochry.

[image: Gate Lodge, Dalmunzie Estate]

With the decline in the employment of servants and the need for this accommodation, most of these properties these days are now owned separately from the main estate and its house.

Answer (score 1):

It's often referred to as a **cottage**, a **tenanted cottage** or an **estate cottage**.